# Problems porting Kryonet library from jar to GWT format

Tags: xml, gwt, transform, kryonet

I'm trying to port the Kryonet to the GWT format. I'm building the GWT.XML but when I launch my GWT app, I have 2 error reported (I don't know where).

I put the code here. Can you help me to port this wonderful library to the GWT compiler?

kryonet.gwt.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit trunk//EN" "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
<module rename-to="com.esotericsoftware.kryonet">
    <source path="kryonet">
        <include name="Client.java"/>
        <include name="Connection.java"/>
        <include name="EndPoint.java"/>
        <include name="FrameworkMessage.java"/>
        <include name="JsonSerialization.java"/>
        <include name="KryoNetException.java"/>
        <include name="KryoSerialization.java"/>
        <include name="Listener.java"/>
        <include name="Serialization.java"/>
        <include name="Server.java"/>
        <include name="TcpConnection.java"/>
        <include name="UdpConnection.java"/>
        <include name="rmi/ObjectSpace.java"/>
        <include name="rmi/RemoteObject.java"/>
        <include name="rmi/TimeoutException.java"/>
        <include name="util/InputStreamSender.java"/>
        <include name="util/TcpIdleSender.java"/>
    </source>   
</module>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this would only be possible if you manually rewrite large portions of the kryonet library. It makes heavy use of Java I/O (e.g. InputStreams, Sockets, ...) which is not available in a GWT environment.

There are numerous other solutions for RPC in GWT. E.g. native GWT RequestBuilder and a number of REST connectors you could use instead.